# Unable to find bundled java version. flutter doctor

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, flutter-doctor

I'm facing this issue on windows after upgrading **Android Studio** to **Electric Eel**.

`flutter doctor` returns:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1105], locale en-US)
Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.3)
    X The current Visual Studio installation is incomplete. Please reinstall Visual Studio.
[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
[√] VS Code (version 1.74.3)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

[image: Android Studio (version 2022.1) Unable to find bundled Java version.]

---

I've tried adding a JAVA_HOME kind of solution but didn't work for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggesting an edit to my answer. I can not add it to my answer since i have not tested that step, but i added it as a comment in case someone faces could find that extra step useful!

Answer (score 3):

I had that problem today after updating **Android Studio**, and found an answer here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118502

---

The solution is basically:

1. Go to your **AndroidStudio** folder (normally `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio` in **Windows**)
2. Copy the content of **jbr** and paste the content into **jre** folder

Comment: @ali-usama suggests further: "After that, if you face an issue while starting your Android Studio then copy the jre folder path and add it to the environment variable."

Answer (score 1):

Quick workaround from here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118502#issuecomment-1384954269

Run in the terminal:

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents
ln -s jbr jre
```

*solution for MacOS